# Discord.js how to cache buttons

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, discord.js

I want to make a poll command, and it works just fine, until the bot restarts. After that, whenever a button is clicked, it says button.clicker.user is null. I tried to use `button.fetch()` but that is not a function. Here is my current code:

```js
client.on('clickButton', async button => {
        try {
       await button.fetch(); //not a function
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        try {
            await button.clicker.fetch();
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        
       try {
            await button.message.fetch();
       } catch(err) {
           console.log(err)
       }
        console.log(button.partial); //undefined so I had to use no condition
        if(!button.message.author === client.user) return;
        var checkVoted = new RegExp(`${button.clicker.user.tag}:.+`); //error says cannot read tag of null if I restarted bot
        var a = [];
```

My goal: allow buttons to be clicked with the user property even after the node process restarts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided in your question should already be working.

You are using `await button.clicker.fetch();` which will fetch the user and member properties of the clicker.

```js
client.on('clickButton', async button => {
    console.log(button.clicker); // { user: null, member: null, fetch: [AsyncFunction: fetch] }
    await button.clicker.fetch();
    console.log(button.clicker.user.tag); // username#1234
})
```

Comment: Well I fixed it anyways by changing it from event 'clickButton' to client.ws event 'INTERACTION_CREATE', but I tried that before, which didn’t work. Maybe I did something wrong, but I might try it